# How can i create frame with python that i can put a picture into frame

Tags: python, image-processing

I want to put my pic in my frame.I used this cod :

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('Pic.jpg')
frame = Image.open('Frame.jpg')
size1 = 354,362
paste_point = 69,339
Pic = img.resize((size1))
frame.paste(img, (paste_point))
frame.show()
```

When i run the program, my pic doesn't put in my frame.
How can i create a frame in python

Comment: what you exactly want to have two pic in one frame

Comment: I want put my pic into frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*your question solution depends always on your pic size and frame size ,so code must be adjusted according to pixel size of your pic*

i am giving generic code for your problem maynot fit to your image standards

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('Pic.jpg')
img_w, img_h = img.size
frame = Image.new('RGBA', (1440, 900), (255, 255, 255, 255))

bg_w, bg_h = frame.size
offset = ((bg_w - img_w) / 2, (bg_h - img_h) / 2)
frame.paste(img, offset)
frame.save('out.png')
```

Comment: Thank you Argus.My frame is not empty and in fact my frame itself is a picture.I want to paste frame on my pic,when i do that,the frame covers whole the pic and my pic can not be seen.in your cod , the frame is blank page